# Storing a python dictionary in a Mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

How should you frame an SQL queries for inserting and retrieving python dictionaries from MySQL databases?

The parsed_tweets is an example of a dictionary I'd like to be able to store.

```
for tweet in twtsearch.search_tweets_iterable(twtsearchorder):
    if tweet_limit > 0 :
        parsed_tweets['userid'] = tweet['user']['id']
        parsed_tweets['uname'] = tweet['user']['screen_name']
        parsed_tweets['content'] = tweet['text']
        parsed_tweets['location'] = tweet['user']['location']
        parsed_tweets['retweets'] = tweet['retweet_count']
        parsed_tweets['favs'] = tweet['favorite_count']
```

Comment: Do you have a DB schema? If not (just storing all values in a single column) just store the dump json of your dict. If you have a schema I'm pretty sure mysqldb allows you to do things like call it with `**parsed_tweets`.

Comment: I do have a db schema and I plan on expanding the structure when I can. Here's what it looks like right now http://gyazo.com/163db9070f309eb6f3a32f8f0d8618ce

Comment: Well mysqldb queries are like that: `c.execute("INSERT INTO blabla (col1, ...) VALUES(?, ...)", arg1, arg2...)` you could do something like `c.execute("INSERT INTO blabla (" + ", ".join(d.keys()) + ") VALUES(" + ", ".join(["?"] * len(d)) + ")", *d.keys())` with `d` containing your data in an _OrderedDict_. But this is very error prone, and I'm not even speaking of security. You might what to use an ORM like SqlAlchemy.

Comment: Sorry ignore that last comment if you rea it before the edit, I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the best you can do is store the JSON as a text in mySQL because mySQL doesn't support JSON format. You can do this by importing json and calling the dump method to convert the JSON to text. Similarly, you can call the load method to parse the json back into your program.

If you need to store a json into a DB, try using couchDB

Comment: Another way would be to dump the dictionary to a file and save the reference to the file in your DB.